# How to use variable in one script into def of another script in python

Tags: python

I am new to python script. I was script two script one contains all the def module and in second script i am importing the first script

In Second script i have so many variable defined and these variable is also defined in first script. Could you please let me know how to use second script variable in first script without giving argument.

Here is the code:

```
script1.py:
           import os
           import re
           
           def one():
              print("First Name"+name+"\n")
              print("Last Name "+last+"\n")
              print("Occupation:"+job+"\n")

script2.py:
           import os
           import re
           import script1

           name = "Rob"
           last = "Sussian"
           occupation = "Unemployee"

           print(script1.one())
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: At beginning of `one` you can import `script2` and use the variables then. But the whole approach isn't good. You should follow Grismar's answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solve a problem that all beginner programmers run into sooner rather than later. You'll find that global variables seem to be the solution, but you can save yourself a lot of unlearning of bad habits later by looking at function parameters right away:

```
script1.py:
           def one(name, last, job):
               print("First Name"+name+"\n")
               print("Last Name "+last+"\n")
               print("Occupation:"+job+"\n")

script2.py:
           import script1

           name = "Rob"
           last = "Sussian"
           occupation = "Unemployee"

           print(script1.one(name, last, occupation))
```

Your function `one()` has been given three parameters, which it will expect to be assigned arguments as the function is called, which is exactly what happens in `script2.py`.

Note that I left the names unchanged, but the value of the variables `name` etc. is passed in the call, so that fact that the global variable `name` gets assigned to the parameter `name` of the function `one()` has nothing to do with the names. They could be named differently, and things would work as well - you can tell from `job` and `occupation`.

(Note that I changed the indentation on your function to be 4 instead of 3, which is standard for Python - a good habit as well)

(Another note, the `print()` around the call to the function will only print the return value of `None` - you don't need to print the result of a function that does the printing itself)

If you're trying to avoid passing arguments because you're operating on values that you will be reusing for other functions as well, consider using a class:

```
script1.py:
           class Person:
               def __init__(self, name, last, job):
                   self.name = name
                   self.last = last
                   self.job = job

               def one(self):
                   print("First Name"+self.name+"\n")
                   print("Last Name "+self.last+"\n")
                   print("Occupation:"+self.job+"\n")

script2.py:
           import script1

           rob = Person('Rob', 'Sussian', 'Unemployee')           
           rob.one()
```